# global platform secure channel 2 computation example needed

Tags: smartcard, signature, 3des, emv, globalplatform

I am writing personalization software for a payment chip that implements Global Platform Secure Channel Protocol 2.  I have a tool from the chip vendor that can log in to the card, but I cannot duplicate those computations to come up with my own login.  The vendor tool has just one factory key, or maybe a keyset with three identical parts.  That's all the vendor tool knows, and it can log in to the card:

```
cm> auth
=> 80 50 00 00 08 A0 13 2D 8B C1 E6 6E 9A 00          .P.....-...n..          host challenge:     A0132D8B C1E66E9A
(122317 usec)                       vv indicates SCP02
<= 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 02 00 13 BA 2A    ...............*        seq num: 0013    card challenge:     BA2A16C9DC0E
   16 C9 DC 0E 30 11 F0 19 01 0D BF 2B 90 00          ....0......+..          card cryptogram:    3011F019 010DBF2B
 Status: No Error                                                               
 => 84 82 00 00 10 29 FD 73 3D 5A 91 6C 6F EA A6 56    .....).s=Z.lo..V        host cryptogram: 29FD733D5A916C6FEAA656B82A6B8928
   B8 2A 6B 89 28                                     .*k.(
(75647 usec)
<= 90 00                                              ..
Status: No Error
```

By my reading of the publicly available [Global Platform Card Specification](https://globalplatform.org/specs-library/), my software needs to use the constant 182 (or maybe 181, I tried it both ways), and the Sequence Counter ("0013" here), zero-padded to 16 bytes, to make a Session Key.  Then it needs to concatenate the Host Challenge, Sequence Number, Card Challenge, and "8000..." padding to make plaintext for a signature.  Sign that with the session key and the result should match the card cryptogram.  Once I can duplicate the vendor tool computation, I can use the same code in my perso machine.  Easy peasy.

Working in .Net 4.5 TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider and MACTripleDES, I get values that do not match.  I'm reluctant to integrate Bouncy Castle just to see if it makes things better.  My key computation is verified on [internet calculators](https://paymentcardtools.com/des-calculator), but of course I can't see the card's session key.  Online signature calculators disagree with my code, but they also disagree with the sample data.  All I know is that the signature comes out wrong, or at least different from the working tool.

So I guess the question is, are there examples of this computation available anywhere?  Of course I asked the chip vendor first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example in Python is the Asterix project:
https://github.com/suma12/asterix

Minor chopping up of SCP02.py in that project was enough to run and duplicate my sample data.